# datalist eval passed to javascript not workig

Tags: javascript, asp.net, datalist

I am passing eval value from datalist to javascript function but it is not passed. "First_Name" is not passed but when I passed "Job_Id" parameter then it successfully display the value. How can I pass "First_Name". Below is my code:

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test" %>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Multiple values</title>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowModalPopup(name) {
            alert(name);
            return false;         
        }       
    </script>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
   
    <div style="width: 100%;">
        <asp:DataList ID="dlJobs" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="1"
            DataKeyField="Job_Id" CellPadding="10" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" Width="100%"
            OnItemCommand="dlJobs_ItemCommand">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div style="font-size: small; float: right; margin-left: 20px;">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkContactReferrer" Text="Contact Referrer" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Job_Id") %>'
                        CommandName="ContactReferrer" Style="background: #4E9CAF; padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
                        text-align: center; border-radius: 5px; color: white; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none;
                        margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px;" OnClick='<%# "return ShowModalPopup(" +Eval("First_Name") + " );" %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name is a string value. You must add double quote to call ShowModalPopup method like the following.

```
ShowModalPopup("Jon")
```

Double quote is missing in your code.

```
OnClick='<%# "return ShowModalPopup(\"" + Eval("First_Name") + "\");" %>'
```